# how to work with boostrap in polymer?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer, polymer-1.0

i want to use polymer, but for UI design i want to use bootstrap , so is it possible to use it ? i mean if i create component then i need to import bootstrap css and js in it. that i can do , but then i need to import for each and every component , so at run time , will it download bootstrap files for each component or just download it once ? i have tried it once , but need to know from community. so, i hope to get best answer so can find some work around , and is there any other library for designing polymer components ?

Comment: guys don't - vote me. its genuine question. let it raise.

Comment: 1. yes you can use bootstrap with polymer 2. bootstrap will only be downloaded once and used from cache after. 3 polymer is the only library for making polymer elements. but there are other librarys for making web components React.js / x-tags are a couple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a conglomerate of multiple questions, shows no research or effort, is unclear (e.g. a workaround for *what*?) and asks for an off-site resources.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to import css and js of Bootstrap in every component just import it in main index file and use it in every component.

i used jquery in same and its working perfect.